# Truncate NSString to fit particular rect area

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In one of my application I want to show the short version of comment followed by ellipses.

We can easily do this if we use UILabel, as UILabel does it itself. But I am showing this comment in STTweetLabel which does not do automatically. So I need to truncate string and set text to STTeetLabel.

I came across function to truncate the NSString as per the specified width, but I am unable to enhance it to truncate string to occupy the specified the rect area.

Say I have following comment text shown in (320, 100)

"This is very long comment and I want to truncate 
it to 4 lines and followed by ellipses. I can 
truncate it to fit in specified width but getting 
issues with truncating it to specified rect area. 
kindly help me out to get the required behavior."

It should be shown like below in frame (320,70)
"This is very long comment and I want to truncate 
it to 4 lines and followed by ellipses. I can 
truncate it to fit in specified width but getting 
issues with truncating it to specified rect ....."

Is there any way to truncate NSString to specified rect area?

Comment: `STTweetLabel` is a subclass of `UILabel`. Just set the `lineBreakMode` on your label appropriately, specifically, to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`.

Comment: I have already tried with that. Somehow it is not showing .... in the end instead reduce the frame. I have tried same with STTweetExample as well. If I reduce the frame, it does not truncate tail.